# Push sent successfully using JAVAPNS but not received in client device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am using JAVAPNS v2.2 for sending push notifications to iOS devices. While sending 10 different notification messages to the same device, JAVAPNS shows the status as sent successfully for all the messages but in the client device I am able to receive only 6 or 7 of the notification messages. Below is the code I am using to send the notification messages:

```
List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.payload(payload, Certificate.p12, XXX, false, iOS_Reg_IDs);
```

Comment: That's the way pushes work with Apple. They're not going to let you send 10 at a time to the same device.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for your reply. Do you have an idea on maximum number of notification messages that can be sent to a device at an instant through APNS.

Comment: From your tests I'd guess six or seven.

Comment: But why would you want to send more than one push to the same device at a time? If an app did that to me I'd uninstall it.

Comment: I would like to send 10 different information as notifications to the same application.

Comment: Pushes are unreliable to send information anyway. Query a server when your app comes to the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html):

> **Important:** Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not
>   guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to
>   notify the user that there is new data available.

In other words, you are lucky to have one (the latest) push notification delivered. Any additional delivery is a bonus.

To deliver data, simply notify your app, then have your app download the data from the server.